# Google notification error "Unusual traffic from your computer network"

Tags: search, google

While browsing I have received notification on Google "Unusual traffic from your computer network"

We're sorry..."your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now."
See Google Help for more information.

Right now I am using the "Ubuntu 12.04" 32 bit version.

Any suggestion, why this is happens & How it resolve?

Thank you for your worthy suggestion.

Comment: Sometimes this can be happen. I don't know why though.This  happened to me also in past, 1-2 times. The funny thing is that [Google suggests](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en) some anti-virus programs for Windows-Mac (but not for Linux) :P

Comment: You may be making automated queries to Google , or someone using your IP for Spamming. You should consider running malware Scans on your network machines :)

Answer (score 1):

As the notification say, "your computer or network may be sending automated queries".

The error page most likely displays a CAPTCHA (a squiggly word with a box below it). To continue using Google, type the squiggly word into the box - it's how the site know you're a human, not a robot.

If you don't see a CAPTCHA image or if you continue to encounter the CAPTCHA over and over, try these steps in order:

- Check for malware on your computer. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJRqZTNMCMo) in this sense.
- Contact your network administrator

More info: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en&ref_topic=3087987

For future help, you can send a request at Google using [this form](https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ban).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens if some other computer in a close-knit network is infected and sending unusual volume of traffic to google. Eg. in a LAN network setup, external computers and servers view all your peers as a single IP address.

Answer (score -1):

A quick fix > go to preference and remove google search engine. (work in wmvare fusion and Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit Firefox version is 65.0) 27 feb 2019.
Good luck.

Comment: You don't just tell somebody to just not use the thing they're trying to use. This person wants to use Google, not DuckDuckGo, Startpage, or any other alternatives.